# Lost connection to mysqld on a single large insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore data in a table with definition

```
CREATE TABLE UserDomainSummaries (
summary_id              INT UNSIGNED,
user_id                 BIGINT UNSIGNED,
domain_id               BIGINT UNSIGNED,
city_id                 INT UNSIGNED,
state_id                INT UNSIGNED,
country_id              INT UNSIGNED,
visitCount              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
pageViewCount           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
totalTimeSpentInSecs    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
ffVisitCount            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
ffPageViewCount         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
ffTotalTimeSpentInSecs  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(summary_id, user_id, domain_id, country_id, state_id, city_id),
FOREIGN KEY(summary_id) REFERENCES Summaries(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

from a file with single insert with large number of rows totaling to 200MB. But, in between a error pops up saying

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost Connection To MySQL Server During Query
```

I have tried tweaking with the values of

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
net_read_timeout
bulk_insert_buffer_size
max_allowed_packet
```

but to no avail.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Use LOAD DATA istead

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: "The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed..." - your file is about 200MB it could be enough time to loose connection

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. The "load data infile" method does the job. But, the primary aim of my query is to know why is the error popping up in the first case and how to fix that. Anyway, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `wait_timeout`

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it. This timeout applies only to TCP/IP and Unix socket file connections, not to connections made using named pipes, or shared memory.

Beside using `load data`, you can break the single query (big, fat) into multiple queries (small, slim).

Comment: What is your `wait_timeout` setting? And what is the execution for your big fat query?